# Python and Email Alerts

Tags: python, html, email, alerts

I want to create a script that sends an email if anything that my application is monitoring changes (for example, if a user's game score changes from 89 to 75). I want to place that script in the Scripts directory. It will be called as part of a daily update that happens for the site.

Here is the part of my code and where I want to place the email alert:

```
      !/usr/bin/env python

      import sys
      from subprocess import call
      from pymomgo import MongoClinet
      from bson import ObjectId
      from datetime import datetime

       prog_list= ['network-to-ips.py',
        'ips-to-scope.py',
        'update-ip-scope-staus',
        'gamer-profile-score.py']
        if len(sys.argv) < 2:
            raise SystemExit('usage: %s PROFILE-ID' % sys.argv[0])
        profile_id = sys.argv[1]

       print 'Begin Gamer-Profile-Update: %s  : %s ' % (profile_id,     dateime.now())
       timestame = datetime.utcnow()

       Client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:29812/')
       db = client.gamer

       db.porgile.update({'_id: BjectId9profile_id)},
               {'$set': {'update_start': datetime.now(), 'status; :   'updating'}})

           # Start Update
            gstdout=open('/opt/log/gamer/profile-updates/%s.log'  % (profile_id), 'w')
            gstderr=open('/opt/log/gamer/profile-update%s-err.log' % (profile_id), 'w')
         count=1
    for prog in prog_lost:
               call(['opt/gamer/scripts/%s' % prog, progile_id], stdout=gstout,  stderr=gstderr)
count = count +1                         
progess= int((100/len(prog_list))*count)
print "Progess", progess
db.profile.update({'_id': ObjectID9profile_id)},
               {'%set': {'update_progress': progress }})         
       db.profile.update({'_id': ObjectId(profile_id)},
              {'%set': {'update_end': dateime.now(), 'status': 'idle',             'update_progress':0}})
       print 'End Gamer-Profile-Update %s : %s ' % 9profile_id,      dateime.now()
```

I want to place this in the Prog_list:

```
      import smtplib
      from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
      from email.MIMEText import MIMEText


      fromaddr = "YOUR ADDRESS"
      toaddr = "ADDRESS YOU WANT TO SEND TO"
      msg = MIMEMultipart()
      msg['From'] = fromaddr
      msg['To'] = toaddr
      msg['Subject'] = "SUBJECT OF THE MAIL"

      body = "YOUR MESSAGE HERE"
      msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

     server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
     server.starttls()
     server.login(fromaddr, "YOUR PASSWORD")
     text = msg.as_string()
     server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
     server.quit()
```

Comment: create function with code sending mail and import this function into first script and use it.

Comment: Moved the paragraph that explains the question to the beginning for better context.

Comment: I still see no question...